SwiftUI - Landscape Sheet Won't Expand Past Horizontal Safe Area
I'm having trouble getting a sheet to expand past the safe area and touch the leading and trailing edges of the screen when the device is in landscape.
Ideally the sheet would have all the benefits of using .presentationCompactAdaptation(.sheet) and the white background would touch the horizontal edges of the screen - similar to how a sheet operates in portrait.
See image highlighting the leading and trailing edges I would like the sheet to ignore.
Using fullScreenCover is not an option.

import SwiftUI

struct LandscapeSheetTest: View {
    @State private var isSheetPresented: Bool = false
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Button {
                isSheetPresented.toggle()
            } label: {
                Text("show sheet")
            }

        }
        .sheet(isPresented: $isSheetPresented) {
            VStack {
                Text("Some content here")
            }
            .frame(width: UIScreen.main.bounds.width) // Not necessary, but highlights how the sheet only stretches up to the safe area bounds
            .presentationContentInteraction(.resizes)
            .presentationCompactAdaptation(.sheet)
            .presentationDetents([.height(200), .large])
        }
    }
}

#Preview {
    LandscapeSheetTest()
}


Built-in sheets just don't do this. You'd need to write your own sheet.

Could there be a way to add some view that is separate from the sheet that fills those gaps?

@nickreps did my answer helped?

This simply isn't possible using the built in .sheet modifier. You would need to build your own sheet implementation or use a third-party dependency like ManySheets (https://github.com/GlennBrann/ManySheets) which does support this. Note - I'm not affiliated w/ManySheets and am simply making a suggestion to use it.


struct ContentView: View {
    @State private var showSheet = false

    var body: some View {
        Button("Show Full-Screen Sheet") {
            showSheet.toggle()
        }
        .fullScreenAdaptiveSheet(isPresented: $showSheet) {
            VStack {
                Text("Full-Screen Adaptive Sheet")
                    .font(.title)
                    .foregroundColor(.white)
                    .padding(.top, 50)
                Text(UIDevice.current.orientation.isLandscape ? "Landscape" : "Portrait")
                    .foregroundColor(.white)
                Spacer()
            }
            .frame(maxWidth: .infinity, maxHeight: .infinity)
            .background(Color.green)
        }
    }
}

struct FullScreenAdaptiveSheet<SheetContent: View>: ViewModifier {
    @Binding var isPresented: Bool
    let sheetContent: () -> SheetContent

    func body(content: Content) -> some View {
        content
        .fullScreenCover(isPresented: $isPresented) {
            ZStack(alignment: .bottomTrailing) {
                sheetContent()
                    .ignoresSafeArea()

                Button(action: {
                    isPresented = false
                }) {
                    Image(systemName: "xmark")
                        .foregroundColor(.black)
                        .font(.system(size: 20, weight: .bold))
                        .padding()
                        .background(.regularMaterial)
                        .clipShape(Circle())
                }
                .padding(.bottom, 20)
                .padding(.trailing, 20)
            }
        }
    }
}

extension View {
    func fullScreenAdaptiveSheet<SheetContent: View>(
        isPresented: Binding<Bool>,
        @ViewBuilder content: @escaping () -> SheetContent
    ) -> some View {
        self.modifier(
            FullScreenAdaptiveSheet(
                isPresented: isPresented,
                sheetContent: content
            )
        )
    }
}




Unfortunately this is using full screen cover which is not an option on my end. Great suggestion though!

@nickreps maybe I misunderstood the end result. Could you please elaborate on your specific needs?
